# When running on sas it gives ERROR: CLI open cursor error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: database, oracle, sas

```
 proc sql;
 connect to odbc(user='' pwd='' datasrc='');
 create table Hums_Table(compress=yes) as 
 select * from connection to odbc
 (
 select prop.cust_pivotal_id, prop.cust_pivotal_app_id, prop.cust_renew_flag, prop.is_cust_split, prop.cont_agt_brk_channel, prop.cont_plan_id, prop.decision_id_fk, deci.decision, prop.cust_corr_pin_code, prop.cust_corr_city_code_fk, pl.sum_assured, pl.product_name, Ct.City_name from ADMIN.t_proposal_info Prop 
 inner join ADMIN.t_plan_type PL on replace(prop.cont_plan_id,'~',NULL)=PL.plan_code
 inner join ADMIN.t_underwriting_decision deci on prop.decision_id_fk=deci.o_id
 inner join admin.t_city CT on prop.cust_corr_city_code_fk=ct.city_name
 left join admin.T_tele_docsapp_data doc on replace(prop.cust_app_no,'~',NULL)=doc.application_no
 where Prop.create_date between '01-Mar-2023' and '31-Mar-2023'
 
 );
 disconnect from odbc;
 quit;
```

When running on sas it gives ERROR: CLI open cursor error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: This is an Oracle-specific error indicating that you're doing some operation on a string where a number is expected. Do you receive an error when running it directly in Oracle?

Comment: Presumably one of your join conditions is comparing a string (e.g. the replaced `prop` values) with a numeric value, which cause implicit conversion; and the error is saying that one of the values can't be converted. We can't tell you which, you'll need to look at the data types and data to identify the problem - either in the data, or in the assumptions in your code. If it works when run directly then your NLS settings cold be different; but you shouldn't rely on NLS settings, or implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will try to get the data types aligned before doing a comparison. For example, consider table T with a column that you *expect* to be numeric

```
SQL> create table t ( my_semi_numeric_value varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values ('10');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('20');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  where my_semi_numeric_value > 0;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     2 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     2 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER("MY_SEMI_NUMERIC_VALUE")>0)

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)

SQL> set autotrace off
```

You can see in the execution plan, we silently added a TO_NUMBER around the column because you were comparing with a numeric (> 0).  The query will hence run fine as it currently stands

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  where my_semi_numeric_value > 0;

MY_SEMI_NU
----------
10
20
```

but what if someone puts some bad data in that column, eg

```
SQL> insert into t
  2  values ('~10');

1 row created.
```

Now when I run that query, the TO_NUMBER function will fail and hence so will your query

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  where my_semi_numeric_value > 0;
where my_semi_numeric_value > 0
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Depending on your database version, you can handle this yourself

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  where to_number(my_semi_numeric_value default -1 on conversion error) > 0 ;

MY_SEMI_NU
----------
10
20
```

but as others have mentioned, you need to check the datatypes of each column that you are using in the query, including your joins